# How to call MainActivity variables from a fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android had a tab layout with fragments and i had a edit text   field which was declared in my parent activity and i want to  check weather the edit text field is empty or not from a fragment How can i do that This is what i had done but it was showing error
This is my main activity edit text field:

```
search_edit_text = (FloatingEditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_missile_number);
        search_edit_text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        search_edit_text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        search_edit_text.setCursorVisible(false);
        search_edit_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                search_edit_text.setCursorVisible(true);

            }
        });
```

This is my fragment activity:

```
public class Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt extends Fragment {


    static Manual manual_child;    //MANUAL----->PARENT CLASS NAME


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {



         Root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manualmode_ac_fuse_ckt, null);
         manual_child = new Manual();
        (CheckBox)Root_view.findViewById(check_box_count_fuse_after_cnc[i]);

        registerForContextMenu(table_fuse_afer_cnc);
        return Root_view;


    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("MANUAL MODE : CONNECTION");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "TEST  ");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "SELECT ALL  ");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "DESELECT ALL  ");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle()=="TEST  ")
        {

            if(manual_child.search_edit_text.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Empty Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

}
}
```

This is my  logcat:

```
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.developer.milanandroid.Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt.onContextItemSelected(Manual_AC_Fuse_ckt.java:120)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:1909)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2058)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:359)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3644)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3473)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 07:27:25.830: E/AndroidRuntime(28243):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an interface for that. You can create an interface in the fragment which the activity implements. That is a better way of communicating with the activity's views.

See this post for reference on how to do that: [Android: error with on fragment interaction Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753953/android-error-with-on-fragment-interaction-listener#answer-25754781)

Answer (score 0):

Here can be two points.
1. You can use 
FloatingEditText editText = (FloatingEditText)((MainActivity.this)getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.edt_missile_number);
2. use if(item.getTitle().equals("TEST  ")) cond.

Answer (score -1):

you can call main activity variables in fragment like below:

```
EditText edt = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
```