# getSharedPreferences return Null pointer exeption on some devices

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I have App on Google play, on most devices it work just fine but seems like it on some Samsung(SM-G531H,SM-G530BT), HUAWEI, Lenovo devices it crashes when `getSharedPreferences` calls.

I take a reference to context from `onAttach(Context context)` in fragment method (i am not calling `getSharedPreferences` before `onAttach`)

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        mContext = context;
        //init firebase analytics
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
    }
```

I have `sharedPreference` helper class with constructor

```
 public UserStats(Context mContext) {

    CRASH HERE

        sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_USER,Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

        }
```

This is the method in fragment that invoke sharedPreference

```
private void setGoal(int calories){
        new UserStats(mContext).setNewGoal(calories);

        tvGoal.setText("Goal\n" + calories + " Cal");
    }
```

Any idea why it happen? and how to avoid it?
(i cannot debug it i receive crashes in Firebase console)

Comment: Post all the relevant code please.

Comment: Hey, I'm seeing inconsistencies in `onAtttach()` calls as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077086/android-onattachcontext-not-called-for-api-23). Did you check that out? I'd say look for alternatives.

Comment: interesting, but i used getActivity() before and was the same result

Comment: Where are you calling that `setGoal()` method? If it's as a result of some async operation, the fragment might already be detached from its activity and the activity might be gone and all you're left with is a stale context reference.

Comment: Where do you call `setGoal()` from? Also a minor suggestion, in your constructor for `UserStats`, don't precede the parameter name with `m`. Thats against the [code-style-guide](https://source.android.com/source/code-style).

Comment: setGoal() called in onViewCreated() in fragment (there is no click or long delay that call this method)

Comment: `mContext` is not a useful variable, you should call `getContext()` instead which already keeps track of the fragment's current context. If you still get a crash please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: Ok, i will try to change to getContext, but Why mContext is not usefull? Also Why getActivity not usefull?

Comment: Note that if in `setGoal()` you cannot use `getContext()`, then maybe `tvGoal` member will be not initialized, too.

Comment: Isn't `onAttach()` deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in activity use `getApplicationContext()` .

If you are in fragment use `getContext()` .

If you are in adapter class use `context` and add Context parameter of adapter's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

use getApplicationContext() always if available

Comment: Not always. If you want Activity-specific preferences, use the Activity Context.

Answer (score 0):

Use getActivity() in replace of mContext. It does not find fragment's referrence. So , app is crashed.

Comment: i have used getActivity() before, same result i received the same crashes